# Cartesian product of vertex sets of graph.

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

Now what shall i call the operation $\otimes$ which is apparently different from cartesian product of the graphs $G$ and $H$ ?. Moreover, i want this operation to be different from Cartesian  product of the graphs. Shall i call the operation $\otimes$ as Cartesian product of vertex sets $V(G)$ and $V(H)$?

Answer (score 2):

This is the [graph join](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphJoin.html) operation.

From [this Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1691013/how-does-one-join-two-graphs-in-graph-theory) question, the suggestion is to use the symbol $\nabla$ as in $G \nabla H$

Comment: Typesetting-wise, $G \mathbin{\nabla} H$ (that is, `G \mathbin{\nabla} H`) seems to produce better spacing.